# Unity new UI button click able outside of button area, non clickable over button area

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created new UI button in empty scene,

Whenever I click on button its not `click-able` , but when I take cursor slightly above the button area and click, it gets clicked.

I guess Something like offset problem occurring?? Any fix to that?

**NOTE** I have tried creating new scene same result
,also created new project though Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the EventSystem gameObject, it displays which UI element you are hovering, and other useful information.

Comment: yup checked didnt worked, finally reinstalling Unity did the magic

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and errors, reinstalling Unity did the job